# Not able to increase RAM of google colabatory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am currently using google colabs to implement CNN.
While I am training my model my RAM is insufficient and my session gets crash.
I saw this video  and tried but I am not getting options to increase RAM.
Can someone let me know how to increase it. [Video from where I tried to increase RAM](https://youtu.be/DpuJNFYzQaw)

Comment: If you're in the US, you can sign up for [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) which has double the default memory.

Comment: I am not in US. What is the other option?